# Install psycopg2 over ssh - Write failed: Broken pipe

Tags: python, ssh, psycopg2

I am trying to install psycopg2 on remote computer (RPI) via ssh.

If I call "pip install psycopg2" in virtualenv (Python 3.4) it starts. It freezes in stage

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.7.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psycopg2 ... -
```

After few hours I am disconnected with

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.7.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psycopg2 ... -Write failed: Broken pipe
```

What could be an issue?

Comment: Check psycopg2 build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following on [psycopg2](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2) github page.

[image]

Try installing an older version by using `pip install psycopg2==[version no.]`